# gulp eslint output to html retains old results

Tags: gulp, eslint

So here are my gulp tasks:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var eslint = require('gulp-eslint');
var reporter = require('eslint-html-reporter');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');


gulp.task('eslint:reporter', function () {
  var reportFile = path.join(__dirname, 'report-results.html');
  return gulp.src(['./src/**/*.js'])
  .pipe(eslint())
  .pipe(eslint.format(reporter, function (results) {
    fs.unlink(reportFile, function () {
      fs.writeFile(reportFile, results, function () {
        console.log('Done.');
      });
    });
  }));
});

gulp.task('eslint', ['eslint:reporter'], function() {
  gulp.watch(['./src/**/*.js'], ['eslint:reporter']);
});
```

Basically the issue is that after running `gulp eslint` the first time the file reporter-results.html gets generated. Then I go to make a change and it reruns.  When I refresh the page the files reported are doubled.  The list has every filed doubled up. Why is it retaining this history? Is there a way to clear it from eslint?